# Not able to use tf.stop_gradient

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to understand how tf.stop_gradient works and to that end i used this small code snippet

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
w1 = tf.get_variable(name = 'w1',initializer=tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32))
w2 = tf.get_variable(name = 'w2',initializer=tf.constant(3,dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True)
inter = w1*w2
inter=tf.stop_gradient(inter)
loss = w1*w1 - inter  - 10
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.0001)


gradients = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(gradients))
```

Error: TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type

If i comment out the line using tf.stop_gradient the code  runs fine and as expected. Please guide me on how to use tf.stop_gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `tf.stop_gradient` correctly. However, TensorFlow stops the gradients at `inter` by removing all graph connections leading to `loss`. As a result, it will return `None` if you calculate `dLoss/dw2` using `tf.gradients` or `opt.compute_gradients` because [[1]](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783)

> Returning `None` makes it explicit that there is no graph connection between the two.

That's how the `TypeError` appears (`dLoss/dw1` does not have this problem).
Many users (including myself) thought this kind of gradient should be `0` instead of `None`, but TensorFlow engineers insist that this is intended behavior.

Fortunately there're workarounds, try the codes below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w1 = tf.get_variable(name='w1', initializer=tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32))
w2 = tf.get_variable(name='w2', initializer=tf.constant(3, dtype=tf.float32))
inter = w1 * w2
inter = tf.stop_gradient(inter)
loss = w1*w1 - inter - 10
dL_dW = tf.gradients(loss, [w1, w2])
# Replace None gradient with 0 manully
dL_dW = [tf.constant(0) if grad is None else grad for grad in dL_dW]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(dL_dW))
```